# Color/Line labels are being sorted alphabetically in ggplot. How to avoid?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to draw 3 lines from my data set on the same graph, and display them using ggplot2.
I want to manually set the colours and shape to each line.

The problem is that the colours/shape are being set up based on the lexicographic order of the labels and I don't seem to have any control on what is being chosen.

This is what I've tried:

```
px <- 
    ggplot(dataset) + 
    stat_smooth(aes(x=id, y=dataset[,4], colour="2000",  linetype="2000"),se=FALSE, size=1, span=0.1, level=0.90, method="loess") +
    stat_smooth(aes(x=id, y=dataset[,3], colour="500",  linetype="500"),se=FALSE, size=1, span=0.1, level=0.90, method="loess") +
    stat_smooth(aes(x=id, y=dataset[,2], colour="1000", linetype="1000"),se=FALSE, size=1, span=0.1, level=0.90, method="loess") +    
    theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
    xlab("x") +
    ylab("y") +
    ggtitle("px") 

py <- 
    ggplot(dataset) + 
    stat_smooth(aes(x=id, y=dataset[,4], colour="1000",  linetype="1000"),se=FALSE, size=1, span=0.1, level=0.90, method="loess") +
    stat_smooth(aes(x=id, y=dataset[,3], colour="500",  linetype="500"),se=FALSE, size=1, span=0.1, level=0.90, method="loess") +
    stat_smooth(aes(x=id, y=dataset[,2], colour="2000", linetype="2000"),se=FALSE, size=1, span=0.1, level=0.90, method="loess") +    
    theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
    xlab("x") +
    ylab("y") +
    ggtitle("py") 
pz <- 
    ggplot(dataset) + 
    stat_smooth(aes(x=id, y=dataset[,4], colour="B1000",  linetype="B1000"),se=FALSE, size=1, span=0.1, level=0.90, method="loess") +
    stat_smooth(aes(x=id, y=dataset[,3], colour="C500",  linetype="C500"),se=FALSE, size=1, span=0.1, level=0.90, method="loess") +
    stat_smooth(aes(x=id, y=dataset[,2], colour="A2000", linetype="A2000"),se=FALSE, size=1, span=0.1, level=0.90, method="loess") +    
    theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
    ylab("y") +
    xlab("x") +
    ggtitle("pz")
```

This is what I get:

[image]

My data looks like this:

```
> head(dataset)
  id  A  B  C
1  1  0 26 44
2  2  0  0  0
3  3  0  0 46
4  4 26 22  0
5  5 16  0  0
6  6  0  0 30
```

I want to have something like the last one, with these exact colours, shapes and ordering on the legend box, but without having to put ABC before each label.

How can I do this?

PS: Even though I'm using stat_smooth, same happens with geom_line

Comment: Why do you then write `colour="B1000"`? Why not `colour="1000"`?

Comment: Because I wanted the 2000 appear before 1000. Since it's sorted alphabetically 1000 is "less than" 2000

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problems are because this is not how things are done in **ggplot2**. If you are ever using `[` inside of `aes()` that's a sure sign that you're doing it wrong.

Instead of three separate calls to a single `geom`, we melt a data frame and then map variables to aesthetics.

```
dat <- read.table(text = "  id  A  B  C
 1  1  0 26 44
 2  2  0  0  0
 3  3  0  0 46
 4  4 26 22  0
 5  5 16  0  0
 6  6  0  0 30",header = TRUE,sep = "")

require(reshape2)
datm <- melt(dat,id.vars = 'id')
datm$variable <- factor(datm$variable,levels = c('C','A','B'))

ggplot(datm) + 
    geom_line(aes(x = id,y = value,colour = variable,linetype = variable))
```

I've used `geom_line` here because your sample data was too small to use `geom_smooth`, but it works the same way. Once you've melted your data, you control the order by adjusting the order of the levels in factor.

And you can always change the levels to something other than `A` through `C` of course.

Comment: Did this. Nothing showed up.
This is what I have on my "datm"
head
  id variable value
1  1     <NA>     0
2  2     <NA>     0
3  3     <NA>     0
4  4     <NA>    26
5  5     <NA>    16
6  6     <NA>     0
summary
       id       variable         value        
 Min.   :   1   C   :    0   Min.   :   0.00  
 1st Qu.:1627   A   :    0   1st Qu.:  18.00  
 Median :3253   B   :    0   Median :  38.00  
 Mean   :3253   NA's:19515   Mean   :  38.92  
 3rd Qu.:4879                3rd Qu.:  60.00  
 Max.   :6505                Max.   : 100.00  
                             NA's   :7846.00

Comment: @DavidAnderson Then your real data is different from the sample data you showed in your question. (You'll note that if you run my code verbatim, it works.) I can't help if I don't have an accurate representation of your data. In your case, it looks like there are lots of missing values.

Comment: Is there a way to upload my real data here?

My full script is in: http://pastie.org/private/9ohkutctbtznrkcqip42zw

Comment: @DavidAnderson Not necessary. Note that in your example data in the question, the column names are A,B and C. So that's what I used when reordering the factor levels in `factor`. Look at your code. Are your column names actually just A B and C? Maybe you should try to adapt my code a little more carefully...?

Comment: Hmm That's it. The problem was with the names didn't notice that. Now it works. Thanks!

Comment: joran, in another data frame I'm getting this: `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "variable", value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  replacement has 19515 rows, data has 18495

while setting the factor. What could it be?

Comment: @DavidAnderson I'm not doing this anymore. I've already answered your question as originally stated, and then sifted through your full script to fix another completely unrelated error. If you're having _another_ problem, you'll need to isolate it into a reproducible example and post a new question.